# What is the explanation behind this weird hysteresis graph?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, ferromagnetism

We were doing an experiment with Ferrite material to find the Curie temperature of the material.
We found that at some temperature range, there are two loops at the two ends of the curve.
[image: The weird graph]
What is the reason behind this phenomenon?

We find that the area decreases with temperature, as expected, and at room temperature, or temperature over about $185$ degree C, the graph looks normal.

Is this some problem with the apparatus or some known behaviour?

Note: In the graph, the units should not be Tesla and A/m, as the values in $x$ and $y$ axes are actually voltages proportional to $B$ and $H$.

I am also attaching pictures of two "normal" graphs which show up at low enough or high enough temperatures.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the two appearant 'crossings' actually _crossings_, or do the curves only touch and then separate again (which would still be strange)?

Comment: I would guess that somehow, you have got a phase shift in one (or both) of your measurement channels. Just because the other too graphs look "normal" doesn't mean they are *correct*.  If you reduce the amplitude so there is no hysteresis, do *all* the graphs become straight lines?

Comment: Does it change anything if you scan faster/slower?

Comment: It would help if you described your setup better - how does the ferrite body and wiring look like, how is induction B measured? Please indicate values of the fields in standard units. Judging just from the pictures, another strange thing is that they suggest magnetic induction B stops increasing when magnetic intensity H reaches some treshold, which shouldn't happen; only magnetization M should stop increasing, but B should continue to rise with H. Maybe if $\mu_r$ is very high then the pictures are fine as the slope would be very small .